# bash - get directory a script is run from

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

So I'm learning some bash and I'm trying to figure out how to get the directory a script is run from. So given that I have my script `~/scripts/bash/myscript`, if I execute my scipt like:

```
user@localhost ~/dir/I/need/to/run/the/script/from $ ~/scripts/bash/myscript
```

from within my script, how can I get the directory from which it's being executed, so that I get `~/dir/I/need/to/run/the/script/from` in this case. Shortcuts like:

```
DIR=`pwd`
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
DIR=`dirname $0`
```

as far as I can notice, they all assign *the path to the script* to `DIR`, but I'm looking for the path the script was run from.

Any help on this?

Thanks!! :)

Comment: `pwd` should work. Just be sure to call it early enough before you do any `cd`.

Comment: isn't this to get the path to the script itself? what I need is MY current directory, not the script's. if not, can you please point me how to get MY directory with `readlink`? thx

Comment: You are looking for the term **current working directory**, this "directory a script is run from" thing is vague and ill-defined.

Comment: "I need is MY current directory". Current working directory is defined for processes, not people or anyrhing else. Which process do you mean when you say "my"?

Comment: OK, my bad, sorry for the wording. As I said, I'm learning, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`$PWD`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PWD) variable is probably what you need.

```
$ cat >/tmp/pwd.bash <<'END'
#!/bin/bash
echo "\$0=$0"
echo "\$PWD=$PWD"
END

$ chmod u+x /tmp/pwd.bash

$ pwd
/home/jackman

$ /tmp/pwd.bash
$0=/tmp/pwd.bash
$PWD=/home/jackman
```

Comment: You can do this: `scriptdir=$(dirname -- "$(realpath -- "$0")")`